# Delete Related Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a **stored procedure** that deletes related records. If you look at the image below you'll see how a booth has a booth type and hall and a booth type has a `productid` which is then contained in the products table.

Essentially, I am trying to delete a hall and that means also deleting the booth, the booth type, and the product for the booth type.

I don't even know where to begin as I am very new to sql so any guidance or links are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You could set the foreign key to cascade delete if you want to be lazy, but you should always be cautious when deleting data

Comment: @br4d, yeah they all have the FK contraint but that is not set and I do not want to set it. The user is displayed a big warning before it is all deleted. I could do manually in C# but I want to write an SP as I feel it'd be much more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have cascade for delete set up on your table DDL then if youdelete on the parent table the delete will cascade to the child table and their children recursiveley.

more info: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

To manaully delete from each table you need to delete from least depending to most depending table, deleting from child up to parent, using joins to help.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess my question is: How do I collect the data and store it to get to those child items from the parent items. I would need to get all booths that have HallId equal to id passed in parameter. and then for each of those booths go to it's booth type, find the product for it, then the price for that product and finally the price split for that price and start deleting from there.

Comment: Keep it simple and use a DELETE FROM with joins. delete pricesplit from pricesplit inner join price on (stuff = stuff) inner join product on (stuff = stuff) etc

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using joins and DELETE FROM as suggested by @TheMadDBA so props to him/her for that idea. Started with lest depending to most depending

```
USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Exhibit].[DeleteHallAndRelatedData]    Script Date: 7/7/2015 2:30:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


----------------------  DeleteHallAndRelatedData ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER PROC [Exhibit].[DeleteHallAndRelatedData]
    @OwnerId UniqueIdentifier,
    @HallId UniqueIdentifier    
AS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET NOCOUNT ON

Print N'DELETING PRICE SPLITS'

delete spl from 
Shopping.PriceSplit spl
join Shopping.Price prc on prc.id=spl.priceId
join Shopping.Product prd on prd.Id = prc.ProductId
join Exhibit.BoothType bt on bt.BoothTypeProductId=prd.Id
Join Exhibit.Booth b on b.BoothTypeId=bt.BoothTypeProductId
where
b.HallId= @HallId and b.OwnerId = @OwnerId

Print N'DELETING PRICES'
delete prc from 
Shopping.Price prc
join Shopping.Product prd on prd.Id = prc.ProductId
join Exhibit.BoothType bt on bt.BoothTypeProductId=prd.Id
Join Exhibit.Booth b on b.BoothTypeId=bt.BoothTypeProductId
where
b.HallId= @HallId and b.OwnerId = @OwnerId

Print N'DELETING PRODUCTS'
delete prd from 
Shopping.Product prd
join Exhibit.BoothType bt on bt.BoothTypeProductId=prd.Id
Join Exhibit.Booth b on b.BoothTypeId=bt.BoothTypeProductId
where
b.HallId= @HallId and b.OwnerId = @OwnerId

Print N'DELETING BOOTH TYPES'
delete bt from
Exhibit.BoothType bt
Join Exhibit.Booth b on b.BoothTypeId=bt.BoothTypeProductId
where
b.HallId= @HallId and b.OwnerId = @OwnerId

Print N'DELETING BOOTHS'
delete from Exhibit.Booth where HallId = @HallId

Print N'DELETING HALL'
delete from Exhibit.Hall where Id = @HallId
```